# solving differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

solve:

$(1+p)^2r-2(1+p+q+pq)s+(1+p^2)t=0$

how do I solve this differential using monge's method? .Can someone help me with this

Comment: I don't see a differential equation here, but maybe it's just me

Comment: What is $p,q,r,s,t$?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Monge-AmpereDifferentialEquation.html for definition of p, q, r, s, t.

Comment: @cgiovanardi, thank you. I'm not sure if everyone is supposed to know what these symbols mean... Anyway, the OP didn't even bother to edit the question, so apparently they don't need an answer that much